# In what cases does a C++ compiler infer noexcept?

Tags: c++, exception, compiler-optimization, noexcept

Suppose a C++ compiler is compiling a function whose definition is available in the same translation unit as its invocation. Suppose that it does not throw itself nor calls a function that is know to throw. Suppose also no `extern C` code is called, nor a numeric division with a potentially-zero value.

Under these assumptions, will the compiler treat the function as `noexcept`? If not, are there additional conditions under which `noexcept` is inferred?

Specifically, what about super-simple functions such as

```
void foo() { } /* this one */
class A { 
    int x_; 
public: 
    x() const { return x_; }  /* ... and this one */
}
```

?

I'd like an answer based only on the standard, foremost, and possibly also what GCC and clang do.

Comment: IIRC it only infers noexcept for a few special member functions. e.g. destructors unless you specify otherwise. (Will check the standard and get back on this)

Comment: For optimization, compiler has to follow as-if rule. From standard point of view, I don't think that compiler can change `noexcept` of a function.

Comment: @AndyG: See edit.

Comment: @Jarod42: I'm not sure what you mean by "as if" in this context.

Comment: I mean that if compiler can know that no exceptions can occur, it can avoid to generate code to handle exception for that part.

Comment: @Jarod42: Oh, well, great, that's basically what I meant by inferring `noexcept` (except that it only happens when optimizations are enabled). Right?

Answer (score 6):

Almost all functions are assumed to be potentially throwing unless you explicitly use a `noexcept` specifier. The exceptions are for your own definitions of `delete` (deallocation functions), and some special member functions: constructors, destructors, and assignment operators. (C++17)

From [except.spec]

> If a declaration of a function does not have a *noexcept-specifier*, the declaration has a potentially throwing
>   exception specification unless it is a destructor or a deallocation function or is defaulted on its first declaration,
>   in which cases the exception specification is as specified below and no other declaration for that function shall
>   have a *noexcept-specifier*.

#### Constructors

Are implicitly `noexcept` unless any initialization performed for any member (or a member's member etc) is potentially throwing

#### Destructors

Are implicitly `noexcept` unless any destructor for a potentially constructed sub-object is potentially throwing.

#### Assignment operators

Are implicitly `noexcept` unless any use of assignment within is potentially-throwing.

---

Here's some sample code that demonstrates the above ([clang 6.0.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ml6aRaVv0fHgxjhW), [gcc 8.0.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LGT19KiteLXefufS)):

```
int foo() { return 1; }
int bar() noexcept{ return 1; }

struct Foo{};

struct Bar{
 Bar(){}
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(noexcept(bar()));
    static_assert(!noexcept(foo()));
    static_assert(noexcept(Foo()));
    static_assert(noexcept(Foo().~Foo()));
    static_assert(noexcept(Foo().operator=(Foo())));
    static_assert(!noexcept(Bar()));
    Bar b;
    static_assert(noexcept(b.~Bar()));
}
```

Yet another reason to use `=default` or allow the compiler to generate its own versions of your special member functions via omission.

Comment: the point for constructors applies to implicitly declared or explicitly defaulted ones only. https://godbolt.org/g/MW54Ah I suspect it's the same for assignment ops

Comment: @bolov: That is the point of *"is defaulted on its first declaration"*.

Comment: So, you're saying that `int foo() { return 1; }` is _not_ assumed to be `noexcept`? Really?

Comment: @einpoklum: That's exactly what I'm saying, unfortunately. [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nwz5zeNaCGoJEc0q)